# How to sum values in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I know how to count total results:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Count FROM store_items
```

This will give me the total number of unique items in my store. However, some items may have more than 1 quantity. The table is like:

```
ID    Sku   Qty
1     500   3
2     501   1
3     502   6
```

How do I modify the query to return `10` instead of `3` (counting the values in all the `Qty` fields)?

Comment: PHP removed in place of MySQL tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(Qty) AS sum FROM store_items
```

[mysql:sum](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp)

Answer (score 2):

You should group them:

```
SELECT SUM(`Qty`) as `Quantity` 
FROM `store_items`
GROUP BY `Sku`
```

This way you get sums for each Sku you have. So if you have multiple rows of each Sku, they would all be summed.